# Using a Twig variable inside the 'use' tag

Tags: php, twig

I want to dynamically use a Twig template, but for some reason I can't get it to work.

When I add this line, my page crashes:

```
{% use current_page %}
```

`current_page` is set to "birthday.twig", which exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the [Twig documentation](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/use.html) states:

> Because use statements are resolved independently of the context passed to the template, the template reference cannot be an expression.

So unfortunately it is not possible to have a variable `{% use xyz %}` statement.

However, you can `include` using a variable. See http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/recipes.html

Comment: Damn, that's unfortunate. Do you know of another, efficient way to do it? I want to make `index.php?page=birthday` use `index.twig` but simply import the `birthday.twig` body.

Comment: You can `include` using a variable. See http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/recipes.html